# Multiply pandas dataframes by matching row of one to columns of another

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
            min
Intercept   3
Radio       2
TV          4
```

and I want to multiply (or subtract or divide) each element of another dataframe by matching the row name to the column name of the new dataframe

```
    Intercept   Radio   TV
0   1           11       3
1   1            2       7
2   1           5       12
```

Giving

```
    Intercept   Radio   TV
0   3           22       12
1   3           4        28
2   3           10      48
```

In R I can do this using intersect, but I can find a similar way in python/pandas

Comment: apologies: updated above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexing will take care of it, almost like magic:

```
df1['min'] * df2
```

Comment: Is there a way of doing this but only displaying columns in the output where a match was found?

Comment: @fred.schwartz: One way is to use `dropna()` on the result.